# x:Key & TargetType in styles

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, targettype

Is there any difference (or advantage) for use this statement:

```
Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"
```

with omitting the `x:Key` attribute?

I think WPF assigns the key to the same `x:Type` under the hood.

Answer (score 30):

The MSDN documentation for [`Style.TargetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) confirms your suspicions:

> Setting the TargetType property to the TextBlock type **without setting an x:Key implicitly sets the x:Key** to {x:Type TextBlock}. This also means that if you give the above Style an x:Key value of anything other than {x:Type TextBlock}, the Style would not be applied to all TextBlock elements automatically. Instead, you need to apply the style to the TextBlock elements explicitly.

If the resource dictionary key of a style is a type, that style is used as the default style for all instances of that type that don't explicitly specify a style.  Since the target type is usually supplied, the syntax of omitting the key is simply a shortcut for defining a default style.

Comment: ok, just  I saw this in some good  examples and this helped, thanks Rick

Comment: @Manuel: If this answer helped you, why don't you **accept it than**!