# Setting property in control from child in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, visibility

For the sake of simplicity say i have this control called DetailArea

```
<UserControl x:Class="DetailArea">
    <Grid>
       <CustomDataControl x:Name="MyDataControl" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In another control i use my DetailArea

```
<UserControl x:Class="Display">
    <Grid>
        <DetailArea />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CustomDataControl in the DetailArea control has a public Visibility dependency property like all UI elements property that i want to be able to set to Hidden.

How can i do this from the Display control?

Edit: I cannot modify the DetailArea wpf or code as it's in another all which I don't control.

Comment: How do you want to control it? With a Button?

Comment: @LittleBit I just want to hide it permanently. It's not needed.

Comment: Can you add/modify the App.xaml or add a additional Style? And does this CustomControl only exist once?

Comment: @LittleBit No can't modify App.xaml. I can add additional styles. It only exists once.

Answer (score 1):

According to your Answers in the Comments, i suggest you to apply a Style which only affects the mentioned Control. Something like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="Display">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CustomDataControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource KeyOfCustomDataControlStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DetailArea />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note: This is just a Pseudo Code, please modifiy it to match your Environment.

Note2: The `BasedOn="{StaticResource KeyOfCustomDataControlStyle}"`is optional.

---

**Edit**
I've removed the `x:Key="MakeInvisible"` because the style may be not be applied correctly, details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108923/xkey-targettype-in-styles/8109198#8109198) (Credits to @Jack).

Comment: This is a nice approach, looks like it could work well. I suggest removing the `x:Key` as you will not be able to set the style explicitly within the control.

Comment: I wasnt aware of such issues, thanks for mentioning it. The Answer has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot modify the DetailArea wpf or code as it's in another all which I don't control.

Then you *can't* set a property of the `CustomDataControl` using XAML.

What you should do is to add add dependency property to the `DetailArea` class and bind the `Visibility` property of the `CustomDataControl` to this one. You can then set this property in the `Display` `UserControl`:

```
<DetailArea Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

If you can't modify `DetailsArea` for some reason, you will have to set the property programmatically, e.g:

```
detailArea.MyDataControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```