# What is x:key in combination with x:Type in wpf

Tags: wpf

I know resources like styles or ControlTemplates in Wpf using x:Key as follows.

```xml
<Style x:Key="SimpleScrollViewer" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
...
</Style>
```

But I just noticed x:Key ***with*** x:Type as follows.

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Template" 
                    Value="{StaticResource CustomHorizontalScrollBar}" />
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Just to highlight there is x:Type ***inside*** of the {} brackets.

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
...
</Style>
```

Can someone explain or point me to some docs how to understand this please?

Comment: See [Styling and Templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms745683(v=vs.85)), section *The TargetType Property*: *... What actually happens is that doing so implicitly sets the x:Key to {x:Type TextBlock}*.

Answer (score 1):

The `x:Key` does not have to be a string. It can also be, for example, a type. In this case, it's a type.

Note that `<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">` and `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">` are equivalent: [If a `TargetType` is specified, but no `x:Key`, the `TargetType` is used as the default value for the `x:Key`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108923/87698)

Setting `x:Key` to a type (either explicitly or by omitting it) also makes this the default style for that type.